# ES6 call `this` in Array.filter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Does exist a cleaner way to call a static method inside ES6 Array.filter function ?

```js
mine(input = '') {
    var translatedAnswers = this.constructor.translate(this._defaultAnswers);
    var self = this;
    return translatedAnswers.filter(function (answer) {
        return self.constructor.match(input, answer);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With an arrow function I can avoid the `var self = this;`

```js
mine(input = '') {
    const translatedAnswers = this.constructor._translate(this._defaultAnswers);
    return translatedAnswers.filter(answer => this.constructor._match(input, answer));
}
```